# What's the default hash format / algorithm of Active Directory?

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, active-directory, ldap

I'm wondering what format I need to put hashes in to write to [userPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc220977%28v=PROT.10%29.aspx) via LDAP. Apache Directory Studio gives me several options, but I don't think any of them are it. Can anyone document the proper encoding and algorithms used by default for AD 2003r2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't write password hashes into the Active Directory via LDAP. You can [update the "unicodePwd" attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223248(v=prot.10).aspx) via LDAP over SSL. (If you're not using SSL you'll get back a "The server is unwilling to process the request." error 0x80072035).

There's no "supported" mechanism for writing raw hashes into the Directory, though.

Answer (score 3):

[This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269190) indicates that you can write the password as a unicode octet-string (of the plaintext password) to a user's *unicodePwd* attribute. It's described for Windows 2000, but as far as I know this hasn't changed.

[This blog post](http://www.evanhoffman.com/evan/2010/01/13/victory-change-active-directory-password-via-ldap-through-browser/) includes a Perl script which implements the process, and which you can look to for more details. [Here's another example](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4693664&#4693664) in Java.

I think the *userPassword* attribute is an alias for *unicodePwd*, but I don't actually know if that's true.

**Note:** You must use an SSL connection to LDAP to update a user's password; AD will not permit password updates over an unencrypted channel.

Comment: While correct, managing with Powershell is much easier than Perl or Java Scripts.